# using css to swap image with fadein and out but need to work with button as well

Tags: html, css

I have a lovely working solution that when you hover the image it swaps out and fades in the other image however i position a button above the image and wondering if its possible to fade the background as well when you hover the button?

```css
ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 143px;
}
.ty-btn {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.category-switch {
  display: block;
}
.category-switch img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
}
.category-switch {
  display: inline-block;
}
.category-switch .ty-btn > img,
.category-switch img {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.category-switch .ty-btn:hover > img,
.category-switch img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/acoustic-sofa-bean-bags/" class="category-switch ty-subcategories-block__a">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  " src="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/4/category-panel-acoustic-hover.jpg?t=1438185134" alt="" title="">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img top  " src="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/images/category/4/category-panel-acoustic.jpg?t=1438185134" alt="" title="">
      <span class="ty-btn ty-btn__primary">Shop Now</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can achieve it. Let's take it step by step. Using this `~` operator change properties of **siblings**:

```
.category-switch .ty-btn:hover~img.last-img,
```

---

So next you should change HTML little bit:

```
<!--moved button to top-->
<span class="ty-btn ty-btn__primary">Shop Now</span>
  <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  " src="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/4/category-panel-acoustic-hover.jpg?t=1438185134" alt="" title="">
  <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img top last-img " src="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/images/category/4/category-panel-acoustic.jpg?t=1438185134" alt="" title="">
```

---

Little change added `z-index` to button:

```
.ty-btn {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
    z-index:99;/*added*/
}
```

---

This is following Complete snippet

```css
ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 143px;
}
.ty-btn {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
    z-index:99;/*added*/
}
.category-switch {
  display: block;
}
.category-switch img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
}
.category-switch {
  display: inline-block;
}
.category-switch img {/*updated*/
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
.category-switch .ty-btn:hover~img.last-img,/*updated*/
.category-switch img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="ty-subcategories__item">
    <a href="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/interior/gold-class-bean-bags/acoustic-sofa-bean-bags/" class="category-switch ty-subcategories-block__a">
        
      <span class="ty-btn ty-btn__primary">Shop Now</span>
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img  " src="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/4/category-panel-acoustic-hover.jpg?t=1438185134" alt="" title="">
      <img class="ty-pict  ty-subcategories-img top last-img " src="http://2015.ambientlounge.com/images/category/4/category-panel-acoustic.jpg?t=1438185134" alt="" title="">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Also another great solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Move your `:hover` test higher in the DOM tree:

```
.category-switch:hover img.top {
  opacity:0
}
```